# Unable to select image or table in an RTF field using a mouse in Chrome

Tags: rtf

I am unable to select a image or table in an RTF field using a mouse in Google Chrome. This is possible in IE and Firefox.

Please see the images for clarification.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to select tables and images in Chrome, but it works differently (and not as nicely) as it does in IE.

**Images**

In IE, you can click on an image to select it. The image now has 'anchors' so you can see that it's selected. Clicking the Image button opens the image popup which allows you to modify the image properties.

In Chrome, you can select the image by dragging the cursor from right before to right after the image. No anchors are shown, but the background color changes to blue. Clicking the Image button opens the image popup which allows you to modify the image properties.

**Tables**

In IE, you can click on one of the borders of a table to select it. The table now has 'anchors' so you can see that it's selected. Clicking the Table button opens the table editor which allows you to modify the table.

In Chrome, you can select the table by dragging the cursor from right before to right after the table. No anchors are shown, but the background color changes to blue. Clicking the Table button opens the table editor which allows you to modify the table.

Note that it helps if your tables have borders in the rich text. If they don't have borders, it is sometimes very hard to select the table in Chrome!

Note: I tested this on 2011SP1.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...and easy solution can;t it be possible by mouse as i can do in IE, i can select image by click on that image and using of the toggle nodes i can resize the image?

Comment: You could report it as a bug, maybe SDL will solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a quick look through the known issues and didn't see anything about this issue, for both 2011 and 2013.

Occasionally a new version of a browser can have some minor issues in the SDL GUI, SDL support is very quick to issue hotfixes, I'd recommend submitting a support ticket to get this one resolved.

Comment: how can i submit a support ticket?please guide

Comment: Your organisation or your client will have been given the details of how to create a support ticket, you need credentials that are supplied to you.